# Is there a workaround for key.open_write not being implemented in boto?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I have a Python iterator backed by a DB query (a MongoDB cursor in this case). I'm trying to write its contents as a text file on S3, using boto.

The simplest way to do this is to concatenate everything into a string and call key.set_contents_from_string. However, this won't work well for large amounts of data (possibly 1GB+).

```
s = ""
for entry in entries:
  s += entry
k.set_contents_from_string(s)
```

Ideally, I'd use key.open_write() so I can write each entry to S3 as I iterate... but that function isn't yet implemented by boto.

```
k.open_write()
for entry in entries:
  k.write(entry)
```

How can I work around this? Is there perhaps a way to wrap an iterator to behave like a file object, so that I could use key.send_file?

Comment: I think the main reason open_write isn't currently implemented is that S3 requires you to send a Content-Length header in the request and there is no way to know that value in this situation.  Do you know the total size of the data you will be writing?

Comment: Thanks for the details, gamaat. I don't know the total size, as I'm reading it as I go from the DB. One way to implement this might be for boto to buffer the writes, and to use S3's multi-part upload to send them in chunks (with a known size).

Comment: Possibly.  The minimum size for a part is 5MB and you can have as many as 1024 parts.  5MB may not be too big to cache in memory.  Depends on your hardware, really.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm running this on Heroku for now, so the hardware spec is unknown. This is also why I don't just write it to a file and read from there. So from what you say, there's really no way to write 5MB+ of DB data to S3 using boto without loading at least 5MB in memory?

Comment: If you don't know the size up front, there is no way to write a Content-Length header for the PUT request.  And S3 does not support chunked transfer encoding.  So, it's not really a boto thing, it's an S3 thing.